# Context API function causing an infinite loop?

Tags: reactjs

I am having an issue with context api function when called is causing an infinite loop for some reason. I isolated a lot of code to find out the culprit yet I have to idea what is causing this, and I also made sure there are no dependencies or use effect related to the context action. could putting a context action inside a function in a functional component might cause this ?

```js
const items =  (program: convertedArray) => {
      // this function is causing an infinate loop 
      context.SetCheckBoxGlobalMulti({ asdasdasd: true });
      const itemsElements = Object.values(program)
        .filter((el) => el)
        .flatMap((items) => items);
      return itemsElements;
   };


  return <div>{items(program)}</div>;
};
```

Comment: Can you show what SetCheckBoxGlobalMulti is doing, how your context is declared and imported, etc...

Comment: its a clean action function that adds and object in to a context state. I even made a separate action for since I thought it might be the issue

Comment: well if your function is updating the context that is then used, yes it's gonna trigger an infinite loop, but with the data available in your example it's not possible to help much more.

Comment: it is updating the context but I do this all the time , but not inside a function any idea where to call the function then  ?

Comment: again without showing what is rendered in the comment, how the context is displayed and updated, not much more we can do

Answer (score 1):

Your example is missing the context handling at the parent level, so it is only possible to guess what is happening. Most likely the problem is that `context.SetCheckBoxGlobalMulti({ asdasdasd: true });` will cause infinite loop as you create a new object on every call, which react will identify as a change that will cause rerender.